# HTTP Status 406 - Not Acceptable

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, glassfish

Есть три сервера, на всех задеплоино одно и то же приложение .
Есть запрос, который возвращает json.
На двух серверах из трех запрос обрабатывается и вовзращает json, а на третьем запрос уходит в обработку, но не возвращает json, а только это:
HTTP Status 406 - Not Acceptable

type Status report

messageNot Acceptable

descriptionThe resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

Зависимости для json подключены корректно (иначе как объяснить, что на двух серверах все проходит нормально). 
В чем может быть причина?

Включил уровень логгирования TRACE, нашел вот такой эксепшен:

TRACE - Method [json] returned [<200 OK,com.stm.secure.model.Login@17d0fe75,{}>]

TRACE - Error handling return value [type=org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity] [value=<200 OK,com.stm.secure.model.Login@17d0fe75,{}>]
Controller [com.stm.secure.controller.LoginController]

Method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.stm.secure.controller.LoginController.json()]
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:260)

Spring, сервер GlassFish 4

Comment: Включите максимальное логирование и изучайте лог.

Comment: пожалуйста, добавьте эту информацию в вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Таки решилось - в новых деплоях по какой-то причине отсутствовала зависимость 
jackson.core с artifactId:jackson-databind. Удалил зависимости, переконфигурировал pom.xml, добавил их же и снова переконфигурировал.
Напоролся, когда хотел заменить стандартный Jackson2HttpMessageConverter на кастомный https://dzone.com/articles/customizing - всплыла ошибка о том, что невозможно импортировать класс com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;